# How do I maintain model alterations after deleting a Rig?

Tags: modeling, rigging

I bought this model online a few days ago that came fully rigged and made some alterations to it utilizing that rig. However, every time I try to delete the rig the model goes back to its original form and does not stay the way I want it to be **(Example below)**. Does anyone know how to maintain the alterations of my model when deleting the rig?

**PS**: I'm a noob to blender, so I don't know much about it.

**PSS**: Something else to note is that the model also has a **mirror object modifier** for the entire body, just in case that helps, too.

[image]

Comment: Try to select the mesh (character) and then use the RMB >> Parent >> "Clear and Keep Transformation" ... before deleting the Armature.

Comment: Also accessed directly via Alt-P > Clear and Keep Transform.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the modifications you made in two ways:

The first is to apply the Armature modifier in its own submenu in the modifiers panel. For this you must keep in mind that the Armature modifier should be at the top of the modifier list to avoid problems with other modifiers.

[image]

The second way is (while the object(s) are selected) go to the object menu, convert submenu, mesh option. What this will do is apply all the modifiers such as the mirror or the subdivision if they have these modifiers, so if you do not want these to be applied you should delete them first.

[image]

Finally, from what I see, the distortion that your character has may be because it has a scale transformation applied, first check the object's transformations in the transformations panel, the scale should have the same value on all three axes .

[image]

You can also reset the transformations, in this case by pressing Alt+S you can reset the scale to its default value. You can also press Alt+G to reset the position and Alt+R for rotation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the Armature modifier on the mesh object, before you delete the armature. Modifiers work on the mesh data without changing it, which in the case of the Armature modifier lets you pose and re-pose models without error slowly building up. Imagine bending a clay model over and over. Not so great. You’d have to tweak it pretty much every time to keep it looking right around the joints. Now imagine that somehow, every time you pose it, you start with the original model at the base position. That’s what modifiers are like. They’re very handy when you think you might want to make some changes to something later, but you don’t want to have to undo several steps. TYJ for modifiers.